# How to scroll the page when clicking on down arrow using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

An array is having 17 items and I am working on a functionality which needs to display the first 5 items of an array when the page is loaded, then if we click on down arrow then the next 5 items need to show, then for another click need to show the remaining items and similar to up arrow also. How can I achieve this by using only javascript or angularjs. Following is the code which I tried so for.

```js
var vm = this;

vm.dataoptions = [
                {title: 'data1', state: 'app.data1'},
                {title: 'data2', state: 'app.data2'},
                {title: 'data3', state: 'app.data3'},
                {title: 'data4', state: 'app.data4'},
                {title: 'data5', state: 'app.data5'},
                {title: 'data6', state: 'app.data6'},
                {title: 'data7', state: 'app.data7'},
                {title: 'data8', state: 'app.data8'},
                {title: 'data9', state: 'app.data9'},
                {title: 'data10', state: 'app.data10'},
                {title: 'data11', state: 'app.data11'},
                {title: 'data12', state: 'app.data12'},
                {title: 'data13', state: 'app.data13'},
                {title: 'data14', state: 'app.data14'},
                {title: 'data15', state: 'app.data15'},
                {title: 'data16', state: 'app.data16'},
                {title: 'data17', state: 'app.data17'},
            ];
```

```html
<div class="data-list">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in vm.dataoptions">
            <a ui-sref="{{data.state}}">
                {{data.title}}                
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="data-buttons">
<button><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" ng-click="up()"></i></button>
<button><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-click="down()"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.begin = 0;

$scope.dataoptions = [
                {title: 'data1', state: 'app.data1'},
                {title: 'data2', state: 'app.data2'},
                {title: 'data3', state: 'app.data3'},
                {title: 'data4', state: 'app.data4'},
                {title: 'data5', state: 'app.data5'},
                {title: 'data6', state: 'app.data6'},
                {title: 'data7', state: 'app.data7'},
                {title: 'data8', state: 'app.data8'},
                {title: 'data9', state: 'app.data9'},
                {title: 'data10', state: 'app.data10'},
                {title: 'data11', state: 'app.data11'},
                {title: 'data12', state: 'app.data12'},
                {title: 'data13', state: 'app.data13'},
                {title: 'data14', state: 'app.data14'},
                {title: 'data15', state: 'app.data15'},
                {title: 'data16', state: 'app.data16'},
                {title: 'data17', state: 'app.data17'},
            ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="data-list">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="data in dataoptions | limitTo:5:begin">
              <a ui-sref="{{data.state}}">
                  {{data.title}}                
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="data-buttons">
  {{begin}}
  <button ng-show="begin>0" ng-click="begin = begin - 5"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ></i><</button>
  <button ng-show="begin<dataoptions.length" ng-click="begin= begin +5"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" ></i>></button>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

you can do something like that,with limitTo, angular 1.4+ needed

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using angular 1.6.0, but still I can see the first 5 elements only and not able to display the next 5 when I click on arrow button.

Comment: maybe because in your code, the ng-click event is on <i> tag not on <button> tag